# Get the difference between 2 Strings using regular expressions

Tags: java, regex

Is it possible given 2 strings to get the difference using regular expressions. The length of the examples can vary. For example now it's only Id, Name, and Age. However, it could happen that for other examples they include additional properties. So they could be Id, Name, Age, Occupation, Address, etc.
For example I have

**example1:**

```
"Id = xcv-sd234-2 \n
Name = joe \n
Age = 32 \n"
```

**example2:**

```
"Id = xcv-sd234-2 \n
Name = Chloe \n
Age = 32 \n
Occupation = driver"
```

**Desired outcome:**

```
"Name = Chloe \n
Occupation = driver"
```

Comment: Title of question is misleading.

Comment: Where are the regular expressions? You haven't included any in the question. It looks like you're actually trying to diff two arrays (or something like that?). Can you please include a [mcve] of the problem, rather than a fuzzy set of requirements with no code.

Comment: not clear what are you doing

Comment: My apologies. I edited the question and the title. Would this be clearer? Please let me know thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split on new line character and compare strings for strict equality (however you do that in Java). Shouldn’t even need regex for that.

Comment: You can provide an example by this: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#difference(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)\

Comment: Good point. Thank you. Was just curious if it is possible with regex.

Comment: What you might do with Regex would probably end up being the same thing that I recommended here using available string methods and operators. I don’t think it would be worth it, unless there was some nuance to how you are comparing the strings, that goes beyond equality of characters. In that case, you would still only use regex to make a comparison of the individual strings.